# How to use arquillian to test EJB calling webservices using @webserviceref annotation

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to use arquillian to test one method of an EJB using a webservice through @WebServiceRef annotation

In my method decorated by `@Deployment` I declared the resource

```
 @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addPackages(true, ....  PortType.class.getPackage())
                .addAsResource("test-my.wsdl","my.wsdl")
                .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/beans.xml", "beans.xml").addAsManifestResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml");

    }
```

Then I coded the bean as following

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class WSBean {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "/my.wsdl")
    PortType portType;

    public void test() throws Exception{
        portType.lireAdresseClient(null, null);
    }
}
```

and the test

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class WSintegrationTest extends DefaultServicesIntegrationTest {

@Deployment
....

    @Inject
    private WSBean wsBean;

    @Test
    public void testAppel() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TEST APPEL");
        wsBean.test();
    }
}
```

Can I do that with Arquillian ?
How can I fix it ?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want you can take  a look at https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxws you will find examples of JAXWS with its Arquillian test.